# Pass search string extra as intent to Google Autocomplete

Tags: android, google-places-autocomplete

I have an activity before going to `autocomplete activity`. I want to send a data from the previous activity as a `String` `extra` to Google Autocomplete and display it as a **query string** on the search bar. Is this possible?

Here is my code

```
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So far, I couldn't received solutions so i tried checking the `PlaceAutocomplete.class` and found the solution i've been looking for.

by looking at

```
public final PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder zzh(@Nullable String var1) {
        if (var1 != null) {
            this.intent.putExtra("initial_query", var1);
        } else {
            this.intent.removeExtra("initial_query");
        }

        return this;
    }
```

And calling `Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).zzh("dasdas").build(this);`

solved the problem.
Saving this for future reference

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Yes, it is possible. Please follow the steps:

**Step1:** Send your search string from one activity to another using `intent.putExtra(..)` [as we always do]

**Step2:** Receive the string in next activity using `getStringExtra(..)` [as we always do]

**Step3:** Declare a Global Object before `onCreate()`:

```
public PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;
```

**Step4:** Initialize it:

```
autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
```

**Step5:** Next, Cast the search bar to `EditText` and set your string as text, as shown below:

```
((EditText)autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input)).setText(your_string); [from previous activity]
```

***Note:*** do not change this line `getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input)` it has to be the same as shown in this solution.

That's it. Hope it's helpful to you. Any issues, please comment.

Comment: Sorry I updated the question, I am using autocomplete activity instead of autocomplete fragment. That's why I want to pass the data as intent

Comment: @RickRoydAban I think it will still work, You can try once.. Anyway steps are very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Autocomplete` class from the package

> com.google.android.libraries.places.widget

Autocomplete has a method `setInitialQuery()`

I would start the activity by passing query string and latlng params as:

```
private void startAutocompleteActivity(String query) {
        List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                .setInitialQuery(query)
                .setLocationBias(RectangularBounds.newInstance(new LatLng(10.637859, 76.691510), new LatLng(11.345122, 77.324748)))
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SOURCE_LOCATION);
    }
```